# How to set value in Select2 using database data in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, jquery-select2

I really need help on my problem, i am trying to set a value in my select2 using the data that i had fetch in my database using ajax.

here is my view in select2

```
  <select multiple id="multiple_assigned" style="width:300px">
          <option value="1">Test1</option>
          <option value="2">Test2</option>
          <option value="3">Test3</option>
          <option value="4">Test4</option>
          <option value="5">Test5</option>
          <option value="6">Test6</option>
          <option value="7">Test7</option>
          <option value="8">Test8</option>
      </select>
```

the data is look like this:

```
0: {users_id: "1"}
1: {users_id: "2"}
2: {users_id: "3"}
3: {users_id: "4"}
4: {users_id: "5"}
5: {users_id: "6"}
```

here is my ajax looks like:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {

                for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                  $('#multiple_assigned').val(data[i]);
                }

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error adding / update data');
            }
        });
```

thank you in advance. i just need to show all the data that i had fetch through my database in the select2. any answer will be really appreciated thanks.

Comment: `$("#multiple_assigned").select2();` add this after for loop in success function

Comment: @MohsinMarui i already add it, but nothing happens :(

Comment: @MohsinMarui it is now working but it only displays only one data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i already got the answer.

```
            success: function(data) {
                //if success close modal and reload ajax table
                var selectedValues = new Array();
                for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    selectedValues[i] =   data[i]['users_id']
                    $('#multiple_assigned').val(selectedValues);
                    }
                $("#multiple_assigned").select2();

            },
```

i just need to declare an array, then loop through it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #use css/select2.min.css
    #use js/select2.full.min.js
    # then add class="select2"
    #Example:
    <select class="select2" multiple>
              <option value="1">Test1</option>
              <option value="2">Test2</option>
              <option value="3">Test3</option>
              <option value="4">Test4</option>
              <option value="5">Test5</option>
              <option value="6">Test6</option>
              <option value="7">Test7</option>
              <option value="8">Test8</option>
    </select>
#then use this script
<script>
    $(function() {
        //Initialize Select2 Elements
        $('.select2').select2()

    })
</script>
```

Comment: Generally it is  search data from drop-down list using select2 class